# Installing java 9 fails on ubuntu - 404 error

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install java 9 on ubuntu 16.04, using the webupd8team repo. I've installed java 8 already on the same machine. Running the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

leads to a 404 error for the last command:

```
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 9...
--2017-09-23 17:53:43--  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/181/binaries/jdk-9+181_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Auflösen des Hostnamen »download.java.net (download.java.net)«... 2.20.250.112, 2.20.250.104
Verbindungsaufbau zu download.java.net (download.java.net)|2.20.250.112|:80... verbunden. ### connected
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 404 Not Found
2017-09-23 17:53:44 FEHLER 404: Not Found. ### 404

download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
```

Is there a way to change the url, or doesn't the webupd8team's repo work anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.net](http://java.net) site is closed now and web-upd8 repository cannot get JDK sources from there.
I suggest you to download JDK 9 from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) site and install it manually according to installation instructions

Comment: I am pretty furious about Oracle